# How can I enforce type hints in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

I want to add type hints for all variables and functions. So I want PyCharm to warn when variables/functions don't have type hints.
By using "Alt+Enter", I can add type hints but it needs manual operations.

If possible, I want PyCharm to add type hints when it is apparent(like as following):

```py
i = abs(-5)
```

to

```py
i: int = abs(-5)
```

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't be doing this: inference is a thing, and python is not c (even c++ got `auto` long ago) to do so.

Comment: @SUTerliakov-supportsstrike OK, but I think there are many cases where type hints would be useful (I'm still a novice for Python and can't specify cases definitely), so I want to enforce it in those cases.